# discrete metrizable space

Tags: general-topology

Im studing topological spaces $X$ with the following property
If $Y\subseteq X$ is such that $|Y| =|X|$ then $X\cong Y$.

Additionaly, suppose that such $X$ is a metric space, I want to prove that such space is discrete.

it is clear that if X is finite then X is discrete. Also I was able to prove that if X is infinite then has  infinite isolated points, and indeed this set (namely $I$) is dense in $X$. This fact implies immediately the case $X$ countable.

For the uncountable case, my idea is to show that if $|I|< |X| $ a contradiction is reached, but im not sure if I can solve the problem in this way.

thanks for any idea!

Comment: Here's an alternative(?) proof for the countable case:
Pick two points $x,y\in X$ and let $r=\frac 12d(x,y)$.
Then $B(x,r)$ and $B(y,r)$ are disjoint, hence one of of the complements, wlog. it is $X\setminus  B(x,r)$, has the same cardinality as $X$. Let $f\colon X\to X\setminus B(x,r)$ be a homeomorphism and set $Y=\{x,f(x),f(f(x)),\ldots\}$. Then $Y$ is a countable discrete subset and hence $X\cong Y$ is also discrete.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/24144/2060) has some answers, and they refer to this recent overview paper (with proofs): [paper by William Rea Brian](http://wrbrian.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/thetorontoproblem.pdf).
Proposition 2.3 in that paper shows it cannot be non-discrete and metrisable, as hereditarily Lindelöf and hereditarily separable are equivalent in metric spaces (to second countable), for the case $\aleph_1$ already.